# Strings failing with $_GET in php

Tags: php, string, get

I have 3 strings that I get from a get earlier in my php. They are actually used successfully earlier in the script, but when they get to the email functionality it fails as shown below:

```
$vagup = $_GET['vagup'];
$misto = $_GET['misto']; 
$nampao = $_GET['nampao'];

$staement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT earlybird FROM databaser WHERE mastppp = :fasto AND feats = :gamerop');
    $staement->execute( array( 'fasto' => $misto, 'gamerop' => $nampao ) );
    $results = $staement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$masto = $results['earlybird'];
$to      = $masto;
$subject = 'Paid $'. $vagup . ' from the script';
$message = 'This is a receipt for your payment of $'. $vagup . ' from the script';
$headers = 'From: theemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: theemail@gmail.com'  . "\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$staement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT stain FROM databaser WHERE mastppp = :fasto AND feats = :gamerop');   
    $staement->execute( array( 'fasto' => $misto, 'gamerop' => $nampao ) );
    $results = $staement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$masto = $results['stain'];  
$to      = $masto;
$subject = $nampao .' paid $'. $vagup . ' from the script';
$message = 'This is a receipt for the payment of $'. $vagup . ' from the script by '. $nampao;
$headers = 'From: theemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: theemail@gmail.com'  . "\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The odd thing is that when I plug in dummy strings, it works then.

```
$vagup = "rambo";
$misto = "mistoblue"; 
$nampao = "heyu";
```

Comment: pass the emails after encoding them.

Comment: Do those variables really hold what you think they hold? Try echoing them out or error_logging them to make sure.

Comment: They do. Just did it. It is almost like they are conflicting with mailing or something.

Comment: when you are passing the emails in query string encode them.

Comment: How do I do that sgt?

Comment: mastppp = : fasto <-- I don't think it will work with a space after the colon

Comment: That didn't solve it Gordon M. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $vagup = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'vagup', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $misto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'misto', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $nampao = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nampao', FILTER_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use

`string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`

to convert the character encoding of string **str** to **to_encoding** from optionally **from_encoding**.

If **from_encoding** is not specified, the internal encoding will be used.

- after this retry passing the emails

[You can find documentation with examples over here!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)